# "Area" vs "Angle" heuristic for triangular mesh vetrex normal calculation

Tags: geometry, meshing

I am trying to compare the two heuristics below for calculating **vertex normals** in a triangular mesh:

1. the weighted average of face normals of the faces incident to the vertex where the weights are the **area** of each face
2. the weighted average of face normals of the faces incident to the vertex where the weights are the **angle** between two edges of each face

The mesh is defined in **half-edge** data structure. When I see the results, each approach seems to be better in some situations and worse in others.

Which one is better in ***general***?

Comment: There's no "general" case. Perhaps you want a smooth transition from one triangle to the next. Or just seeing the detail around the vertex (here is where I can accept the "angle" average). Or remarking contrast in the shared edges (which may mean no average at all). Just choose the best you like.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful response. I think for triangular meshes, **angle** works better since the area can differ a lot from one side to the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An angle is a definitively better solution, because it provides you a local information in a point, where you want to construct the normal vector. An area of connected elements can vary a lot (depending on other nodes, which are away from the considered node). Look also at the example below (like a table board). [image]